# WebSockets in Azure scalable environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, signalr, xsockets.net

I have plain old SOAP "REST" service written in WCF which is hosted on Azure as WebRole. I am currently writing website which will consume this service and show some nice GUI for it. WebSite will be hosted as WebRole too and is written in ASP MVC 5.

Now i am looking for some Synchronization Framework i can implement into both sides (website and service). There will be more clients than web-site (Store app, Desktop client, android etc.)

Now i came to SignalR and XSockets.net but. Can these frameworks be scaled to more instances automaticaly and how that exactly work? For signalR i [found](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus) it uses ServiceBus as background does Xsockets have simmilar? For Xsockets i found some [issue page](http://xsockets.net/docs/known-issues) which look kinda new, but there is not a word about scalability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default XSockets scale over sockets and not SQL or redis. If you want to scale over something else just write your own plugin.
https://github.com/XSockets/XSockets.NET-4.0

Comment: i ll mark that a solution since i have to write it myself and utilize XSockets is pretty much best solution for me. Thanks for answer anyway.